# PHP/HTML - Show PNG image data

Tags: php, html, image

I get the following from the [Edmunds logo API](http://developer.edmunds.com/api_branding_guide/):

```
PNG


IHDR¸X°'·gAMA±üa cHRMz&úèu0ê`:pºQ<mPLTEæææäää»»»~~mnm`a`XZXWYWOQOUWU^`^ikiz|z²³²ßàß¼½¼dedZ\Zªªª¬­¬PRPhjhµ¶µ¿¿¿ÂÂÂÊÊÊÄÄÄÀÁÀ·¸·«¬«pqpåååÃÄÃÛÛÛÏÏÏÎÎÎ¾¿¾QSQjkjÅÅÅÑÑÑ¥¦¥­­­|}|ÜÜÜSUSÚÚÚÙÙÙ]_]ÞÞÞÑÒÑÆÆÆ~~RTRÈÈÈ¤¥¤tvtÓÓÓegefhfããã§§§¸¸¸×××ßßß°°°abaÀÀÀÐÐÐÝÝÝááá»¼»¨©¨cdcÔÔÔ}} âââUVUlmllnl ¡ ghgacamomVXVº»ºËËËººº¾¾¾½½½ÖÖÖÅÆÅ¹º¹ÄÅÄÁÂÁÇÈÇwxw´µ´¡¢¡­®­°±°···ÍÍÍÏÐÏcec   ÂÃÂqsqnonvxvËÌËtutstsdfdyzyØØØ§¨§gig_a_¦§¦`b`¯°¯©ª©kmkoqoTVTY[YwywÕÕÕxyxÊËÊVWVz{z±²±³´³jljuvubdb®¯®´´´[][]^]klk{}{àààÒÒÒqrq£¤£}~}{|{±±±ÁÁÁfgf¢£¢¶·¶ª«ªsusrsrÎÏÎ¸¹¸®®®\^\ÉÉÉÒÓÒprpxzxnpnØÙØUdò    bKGDÎôÙòÿ   pHYsÒÝ~ütIMEà8ít»L

IDATxÚíû{ÕÇgIWËecÁ4×M   Is7@vMÝÍ^r³BP Ð@¤\ZÕbÔT±°RÅZËEjµØVÛÿ©ï¹ÎL²ÝÕäIìó~~ÈyÏe&ïwÞsÞsFÓAAAAAAAAAAAAA2ÀñÐÃóM².Z¼dé£³ýTH*~°$aùÙ~.djV: Éyì+V­~<øQ^~AaQ1d8«$¯tz­,oÍl{gî²¶T¬l®\LHUf#ýêi}´ZR^7®ÓÔ?A*Ö[MOº6lÜD=
å%ä©i}¶&±fÛAsì&w-xÈ¹Ø!LOó¥æ³9¡¾Âù8þ²èÁæP8
rK*ùÛë÷ù% y|h'/"ºyLÕ¸&Ü8ÀíÁ(½¥h+;§zhGiK«ÖFH»ÖÁÓ-¢"äl­ ¤¥gµÎÒÎ4½ð=.&Þò-
qÙ9ßÇ
>ÕÑ£a¿eÌù¢Ëo¹±GÚAí\¨ûMÁ6pK÷vãÒz¸pÒG;è[Ü¢=GvúÊ   Y¨[ú=÷P®5£kwívL.úüõ¼´¦mÏÞ©Dß×Wo6ÔíÏ/YoN?ÿÓ¢?Sábnva%è¿Ý.f®1CráxäÂq&G[y\0zXOõÐT«FB^Ô\Û¹pû8íïY×_Ù©½ä$å´¢ÒèÔÚ}Z²¦l­GîËéB¸þã;¨mx}xOgzìyNôÚ|ªçDòË9GúêO7Ò&göËÛÎBJKÊ7õKájhåÝTÿÒ·®+ÔÅH_y¦[8î3S,AQã¾åÓË#*/X¨R¯³1)në
bÍIEóbßå\®êFçüÁ,Vh<§ú¼|DÖÖþ[Ê¤åÇ¸pó@1'7½P1Ð¤4»HçRVÓyAÝb7Ò+áâLÒãðä
¬"æUFÔµ]Âµ"ÈÔ â"àm-ÎÑf&áÄ8>#äÒ
8mËÒ£ÛHJ~é~ÅØKØÎÄ±ÂôåUjÙ»º|¸ú5Ír%Oa'q¾øáÎî×iÍ(S|ð
z+Þ¨ªÞ\IíoÍpl)ó±¿ôýgDEütqÊ OµäÂ1}ÉÓ4·PÞ*¬of7K/à¨÷ÆRçÜm´w$dY.-Õüþ ÉÛ4«©{¶Â
©æ2¥VDvÂ¼ë×ýJÇ â
üv´AÁq(K,¼¿%¤gÙ3"ÿ
ZüæãQèfþöÈ,Äg¼¤ÂiS  Çb6ªìB¸ ¿Ð<½RëFÈ£ýdÔÓq÷`ê¿sqÛ®­-Nö¬­O@3;áøëÈ!¤~ág\lºwgóFç   Ë½×®§ßf**étføMç«Gf  º¸ébÂ£Zy&á<J¸8«
Xó[æJÚ6Á?.<A8íÓÞOG¸Ã[oò{YÞ":è,öÁ£Ââº¡»Ê-[   yD½"°®ñCnÙ@Èû0½WÞã(ot   ¡ö´ÞÄo#$bñDP".ÃÔßPÐl%"´5I%\Ôæ1eÙbZ,²¨ä$ìQµaËd:±lðæÐÇÉÛþÇîqú§:Àzvrà¨é×þdÎ*á>åO!Má¥¬*©pËæÈ,Mû3<J¼Ñ-=T¯háí@ráé"G¥ðÐÝ<×,Lù5[á´äÂIåâj;6ê2AÂÓ~óÒFnÃU3^ÕÁ9¡Ñ
½;ªú®NO/QÂyí»!,pwø)áÛÕü,'û³Nì¦º¦¸®(-k#  á|áBºAÄ%x¬ó¹V§p,øDøìây³"Y÷a;Rø%«µ01öì8G
æñ¾³pí°­P:ÊÅÜWD3S²t©2îÒæ<À 5ýº©ÏAÁ¸L0&­qL|¿3½5ÎclDÄ(év
\ñáñú7F¸jå{Kaö¼Gkþ
×S q¸fÒEã%}'p%0øðóp» ØÕ!J   1s:Û!Uá(ðÇÄÕ    ¶úxxL°Í@¬2nôµÉ*»,¯Üèª´¤Áa*ÓaÈþÁou§æ¸ÿøªë«û;5Õ+&Ñ~×5¨dy£÷Æ³Â}ÂòúX*á^Ö_pÃpë7Åu7ÚËNà=+Qáô°é¥÷«IÌ'§DvO.N+#SY&âï$Ü~¶].úÚ úÚú3,e1Ø®:liTßè6BÕ}ÐöZãüô+PAR   çmv1KRëæÛGcØùwfp,áû¸ÒZ²>ÛÚíªbnº/¦ª¢lõ¾âLÞÇQ¿6Âüì0Í¤¨3.`M5¾¬bßå:Vû.£dÿä\ZéÁ|ìà±7µ®!¤N;
MïVö;á>ÉÖü²5}Ã7ÚËÛèZÍÙéþø0I8Ú¤A¥]¢
B±ÑtÈÌFBbÌê3a>ö7Ur¹3Î52!K¬½úÏ³'nî=ì8kíÿn³ùËõ/£áÕÂU.P»ÃFá´UÆÑé¿¹ºÝ4£¬u¾0ÃÂ   åDS©KIÓ¥¾vÂY>×ót?\/Jgî4W8nJ±GÅÌê(9Máó<SågW[Å×X#bÏ?Öû%! ü!Ø¡÷°
8pë¶¸Å©ºÖÈõµx¯VN·nÓ"]2MÎ]rZK&R=vÂ5[EQÂ%<&KºÂmJG¸qksÏ9ñõÃ¸³8çÈç÷¢Úæo?\7U
    Që«ªÄ   ÞÎª`Q¼óÍÀÓg6´ãÞ|¸l}Õ+}Þ[¢týÂznîuiï]þO]Ü6^|¯RvÔnt>úE&b²èòµ}ðf4ñ8ïÉ&ùîñL<øá_ÀÅ2ñ;¹ïqiÜ½ûEÞÜÜÜ¯(»¡t`×^¶uRS2wÂÙ%õ ps8_:ìÎÜyZ÷Íl?%2ÿÒãålÛ\yô#éÀLFDAAAAAAAAAAAAäÿÿÄ YÜIEND®B`
```

I want to display this logo on a `<img>` element. Is there anyway to set this data as the `src` attribute? I'v tried setting `data:image/png;base64` and then the data above but it did not work. It just showed unrecognizable characters.

Comment: Perhaps using the GDLib `imagecreatefromstring()`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Comment: @Rasclatt that didnt work either :/ still prints the unrecognized characters

Comment: Put that data into `somefile.png` and then use it like any other file. Everything else is a bad idea. If you have, at any point, copy/pasted this data it is already corrupted. Go directly from the API to a file.

Comment: @Sammitch unfortunately I dont have the luxury for file access. This will be on a WordPress VIP environment and they dont allow access to FS.

Comment: "don't have the luxury for file access" - What access do you have? A few options: 1 - If you have normal WordPress access, you should be able to save the logo locally as a PNG file and then upload as media and reference that file; 2 - If you can run a PHP file somehow (yet can't upload an image file directly), you can write a PHP program that outputs appropriate headers (e.g., Mime Type) and the image code. The problem is that if you are limited to PHP inside WordPress posts (not allowed by default but plenty of free plugins to do that) then you won't be able to simulate an image file because

Comment: ...of the WordPress header, footer, styles, etc. If you are able to run a full standalone PHP file then I don't know why you wouldn't be able to simply upload the image. I have used the PHP-generating-image technique often when I need to pull an image from an authenticate session via a database, though an individual logo is usually much simpler as a static file.